# Local variables in C#

Tags: c#

Error in C# from a local Variable. I get the error "Use of unassigned local Variable 'CostPerFoot'"

```
if (decimal.TryParse(txtFeet.Text, out Feet))
    {

    //Determine cost per foot of wood
    if (radPine.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = PineCost;
    }
    else if (radOak.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = OakCost;
    }
    else if (radCherry.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = CherryCost;
    }

    //Calculate and display the cost estimate
    CostEstimate = Feet * CostPerFoot;    
    lblTotal.Text = CostEstimate.ToString("C");       
}
```

Specifically the last few lines

```
 CostEstimate = Feet * CostPerFoot;
```

Tried switching the variables around and there's still a problem.

Comment: Can you show how you declare the CostPerFoot variable?

Comment: thats not VB...but you will get that without a default value set for `CostPerFoot ` or an `else`.  the compiler is worried when it is not Oak or Pine or Cherry

Answer (score 9):

You get this error because the compiler assumes that it's possible that you use the variable `CostPerFoot` even if it was not initialized(which means it keeps it's default value). You cannot do that with local variables.

You either have to assign a default value explicitly or make sure that it gets a value in any case. If you would use an `else` the compiler wouldn't complain anymore.

```
if (decimal.TryParse(txtFeet.Text, out Feet))
{
    //Determine cost per foot of wood
    if (radPine.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = PineCost;
    }
    else if (radOak.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = OakCost;
    }
    else if (radCherry.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = CherryCost;
    }
    else
    {
        CostPerFoot = 0;
    }

    //Calculate and display the cost estimate
    CostEstimate = Feet * CostPerFoot;    
    lblTotal.Text = CostEstimate.ToString("C");       
}
```

As mentioned, if you assign a default value the error disappears also:

```
double CostPerFoot = 0;
```

another option is to throw an exception in the `else` if that should never happen. It's good practise to handle invalid states(bugs?) by throwing exceptions. That prevents that you overlook it and that a wrong value is taken silently.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the compiler is complaining because of this line:

```
CostEstimate = Feet * CostPerFoot;
```

Because your `if-else-if` block contains no `else` statement, there is the probability of leaving your `CostPerFoot` var value not initialized, therefore having problem in the computation in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into:

> Use of unassigned local Variable

is quite "easy". It just means that you have a variable that you use (in an if, or in some sort of operation, ...) but you never have assigned a value to it before you use it.

Thus if you have the following error in the following statement:

```
 CostEstimate = Feet * CostPerFoot;
```

This means then that either Feet or CostPerFoot were never assigned a value before you use them (the = for CostEstimate so the assignment only counts after the Feet * CostPerFoot is calculated so even if it is "just" CostPerFoot that is not assigned any value previously...the error occurs).

In your case there are 2 possible opsions:

1.) Either

```
   //Determine cost per foot of wood
    if (radPine.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = PineCost;
    }
    else if (radOak.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = OakCost;
    }
    else if (radCherry.Checked)
    {
        CostPerFoot = CherryCost;
    }

  results in CostPerFoot not to be set (aka none of the three text boxes were set).
```

OR 
2.) Feet was never set to a value

From the example you gave it is not clear which of the two it could be or if it is even both options that occur there. Thus you need to check both and if it is possible that neither checkbox is checked make an else path where you set CostPerFoot to a default value (or set it before the if structure). For Feet you would need to check all code above the code you gave out to see if it was ever set to any value (or if it is done in an if if that if is always true and if not.....put a default value into the else path).